# Can't keep chrome driver windows open

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, bots

I am working on a Youtube view bot as a beginner project and I can't keep the tabs open for longer than like 30 seconds. After all 5 tabs open, they start to close one by one

```
def bot():
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(Path)
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    browser.set_window_size(500, 500)

    def home():
        browser.get('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXKxKJv8XOjp5XC1ddJB4yg')
        sleep(2)

    def page():
        videoElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse/ytd-two-column-browse-results-renderer/div[1]/ytd-section-list-renderer/div[2]/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[3]/ytd-shelf-renderer/div[1]/div[2]/yt-horizontal-list-renderer/div[2]/div/ytd-grid-video-renderer[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h3/a')
        videoElem.click()
        sleep(2)

    home()
    page()

while i < 5:
    bot()
    sleep(2)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Is this just a question of variable scope? the browser is opening but then closing with they fall out of scope of the bot function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: there's nothing in this code that closes or quits the drivers/browsers you are starting.  Is this the complete code?